# Mapping Coordinates of One DIV to Another DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image

am having 2 divs with different height and width having image as background.

[image]

my requirement is to get the cropped coordinates of one div, and position that coordinates to another div.. i need the coordinates..
how can i do that.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getBoundingClientRect)… Note that you need to take care of the parent Nodes. If the parents of the div elements have diffrent positions, than you need to take this difference into accout.

The code below assumes that both `divs` have the same parent and are positioned absolute.

```
var bbox = div1.getBoundingClientRect();
div2.style.top = bbox.top + 'px';
div2.style.left = bboox.left + 'px';
div2.style.width = bbox.right - bbox.left + 'px';
div2.style.height = bbox.bottom - bbox.top + 'px';
```